# Proving a sequence converges to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $0<a<b$ Find the $\cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(a^n+b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

So can I let $\epsilon = a+b$ so that $(\epsilon^n)^\frac{1}{n}$ (I would want to use logs but my professor instructed us not to do so)

I know intuitively that $\cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$ and anything raised to the 0 equals 1 but how could I prove this?

Comment: Are you saying $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$?

Comment: you're right so it would be the binomial expansion, correct?

Comment: Note that $b^n\lt a^n+b^n\lt 2b^n$, and therefore
$b\lt (a^n+b^n)^{1/n}\lt 2^{1/n} b.$
Use the fact that  $2^{1/n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, and Squeezing, to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your intuition deceives you. The limit is $\color{red}{\max(a,b)}$

To see this, suppose $a\ge b$ (if not, exchange the names), and factor out $a^n$. You obtain
$$\bigl(a^n+b^n\bigr)^{\tfrac1n}=a\biggl(1+\Bigl(\dfrac ab\Bigr)^n\biggr)^{\tfrac1n}$$
Now consider the logarithm of the second factor.